# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “null”

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error :(
The Errors appear at Donasi.class

This is in class Donasi:

```
 int total = 0;
    for (Transaksi transaksi:donasi)
        total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*(Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity()));
        Locale locale = new Locale("in", "ID");
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        txtTotalDonasi.setText(fmt.format(total));
```

This is in class DonationAdapter:

```
    int minimal = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getMinimal()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));

    holder.txt_minimal.setText(fmt.format(minimal));

    holder.txt_nama_donasi.setText(listData.get(position).getNamaDonasi());
```

This is my Logcat :

```
12-28 14:20:36.283 2579-2579/da.glowroz.donationapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: da.glowroz.donationapp, PID: 2579
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{da.glowroz.donationapp/da.glowroz.donationapp.Donasi}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
at da.glowroz.donationapp.Donasi.loadListDonasi(Donasi.java:134)
at da.glowroz.donationapp.Donasi.onCreate(Donasi.java:72)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Either `transaksi.getMinimal()` or `transaksi.getQuantity()` are null

so check before trying to `parseInt`

Maybe like

```
if (transaksi.getMinimal() != null && transaksi.getQuantity() != null) {
     total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*
            (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

> [**`NumberFormatException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is an Exception that might be thrown when you
>   try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an
>   int , a float , or any other Java numeric type

You are getting **`null`** . Which is not **`int`**. Add **`null`** checking

```
total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*(Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity())); // Problem coming from this end
```

[**`Debug`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) your app. Add **BREAK-POINT** beside **`total`** .

Add **`try-catch`** block

```
try
{
    // Your work
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex)
{
    System.out.println("wrong input");

}
```

Comment: I have edited code. Kindly review.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for null on getMinimal() and getQuantity() before parsing.

```
if (transaksi.getMinimal() != null && transaksi.getQuantity() != null) {
 total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*
        (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity()));
}
```

OR

keep the parsing code in the try block and catch for NumberFormatException. This also helps when getMinimal() or getQuantity() is not null and not number string

```
try {
 total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*
        (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity()));
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
Log.e("TAG","Excepting parsing Integer from string");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`transaksi.getMinimal()` and `transaksi.getQuantity()` should be valid number string to parse as Integer

```
if (transaksi.getMinimal() != null && transaksi.getQuantity() != null && transaksi.getMinimal().equalIgnoreCase("null") && transaksi.getQuantity() .equalIgnoreCase("null") && !transaksi.getMinimal().isEmpty() && !transaksi.getQuantity().isEmpty()) {
     total += (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getMinimal()))*
            (Integer.parseInt(transaksi.getQuantity()));
}
```